# .OGG file uploading on Local server but not on Production

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, ogg, server-configuration

We have an angular application.
backend is developed in Codeigniter 3.
OGG file is uploading in the local environment.
But throw errors in a Production environment.
The file type is allowed in validation.
Also,[image] check the mime type in the config folder.
Could not find why it's not uploading on production.
Looking forward to any assistance.

Comment: how does the `'ogg'`entry in your application/config/mimes.php look like? Also, what is the size of the file? Did you try with a small ogg file to double-check?

Comment: 'ogg'   => array('audio/ogg', 'video/ogg', 'application/ogg'),
in mimes.php file.
yes I also tried a file  < 1mb but same result.

Comment: eventually you might need to configure your production server: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media and https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.audio.php